# Generate Dynamic year wise tables based on input dates in react Js

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON data like below

[   {"id" : "1", "category" : "A", "Date" : "2000-02-20"},  {"id" : "2", "category" : "B", "Date" : "2000-03-11"},  {"id" : "3", "category" : "C", "Date" : "2000-05-11"}, .. .. .. {"id" : "4", "category" : "C", "Date" : "2010-01-20"},  {"id" : "5", "category" : "A", "Date" : "2010-04-02"},  {"id" : "6", "category" : "B", "Date" : "2010-06-10"},  ...     ...     ..  {"id" : "998", "category" : "C", "Date" : "2022-08-14"},    {"id" : "999", "category" : "B", "Date" : "2022-09-15"},    {"id" : "1000", "category" : "A", "Date" : "2022-07-10"} ]

I need the total count of records data of each category to be displayed in year wise table format like below based on time period in between 2 input dates, only for the years in that time period not for all the years available in data.

For example if i input dates as 2020-05-15 and 2022-05-30 it should be like below.

I am struggling to write the logic dynamically generate year wise tables only for the selected dates, please help me to get the solution for it.

[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry8q4.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of filtering by the date.

```js
const values = [{ "id": "1", "category": "A", "Date": "2000-02-20" }, { "id": "2", "category": "B", "Date": "2000-03-11" }, { "id": "3", "category": "C", "Date": "2000-05-11" }, { "id": "4", "category": "C", "Date": "2010-01-20" }, { "id": "5", "category": "A", "Date": "2010-04-02" }, { "id": "6", "category": "B", "Date": "2010-06-10" }, { "id": "998", "category": "C", "Date": "2022-08-14" }, { "id": "999", "category": "B", "Date": "2022-09-15" }, { "id": "1000", "category": "A", "Date": "2022-07-10" }]
const calcRecords = (begin, end) => {
    let setBegin = new Date(begin);
    let setEnd = new Date(end);
    console.log(setEnd);
    
    //If you need to know the value of it id's
    console.log(values.filter((val) => {
        const recordDate = new Date(val.Date);
        //console.log(recordDate);
        if (setBegin < recordDate && recordDate < setEnd ) return true;
        return false;
    }).reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => Number(previousValue.id) + Number(currentValue.id)))
    
    //If you need to know how many elements were found
    console.log(values.filter((val) => {
        const recordDate = new Date(val.Date);
        //console.log(recordDate);
        if (setBegin < recordDate && recordDate < setEnd ) return true;
        return false;
    }).length)
 
}
calcRecords('2000-02-20', '2010-01-20');
```

Comment: Thank you , but this is not the expected output, in the data only one record is present on 2010 January under category C, but in your output 5 and 2 are displaying. What i need is the number of records for each category should be displayed month wise for each year from the input dates.. if no records in any month should display 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example where you do this by the category

```js
const values = [{ "id": "1", "category": "A", "Date": "2000-02-20" }, { "id": "2", "category": "B", "Date": "2000-03-11" }, { "id": "3", "category": "C", "Date": "2000-05-11" }, { "id": "4", "category": "C", "Date": "2010-01-20" }, { "id": "5", "category": "A", "Date": "2010-04-02" }, { "id": "6", "category": "B", "Date": "2010-06-10" }, { "id": "998", "category": "C", "Date": "2022-08-14" }, { "id": "999", "category": "B", "Date": "2022-09-15" }, { "id": "1000", "category": "A", "Date": "2022-07-10" }]
const calcRecords = (begin, end) => {
    let setBegin = new Date(begin);
    let setEnd = new Date(end);
    
    const filteredData = values.filter((val) => {
        const recordDate = new Date(val.Date);
        //console.log(recordDate);
        if (setBegin <= recordDate && recordDate <= setEnd ) return true;
        return false;
    })
    
    //This gets the categories and removes duplicates
    const categories = [... new Set(filteredData.map(record => record.category))];
    
    categories.forEach(cat => {
      //How many entries this category has 
      console.log(`Category ${cat} has ${filteredData.filter(record => record.category === cat).length} items`)
      //Calculates the sum of the id's 
      console.log(`Category ${cat} sum of Id's is ${filteredData.filter(record => record.category === cat).reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + parseInt(currentValue.id), 0)} items`)
    });
 
}
calcRecords('2000-02-20', '2022-07-10');
```

Comment: Thank you , this gives result for count of categories directly, but not in year and month wise. What i need is the number of records for each category should be displayed month wise for each year from the input dates.. if no records in any month should display 0. Sorry I am new to react, so couldn't able to write the logic properly.